# How to de-normalize data with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe created out of CSV file.
The dataframe looks like this

```
srvr_name log_type       hour  
server1   impressionWin  18:00:00 
server1   transactionWin 18:00:00 
server2   impressionWin  18:00:00 
server2   transactionWin 18:00:00
```

What I would like to get from this is:

```
srvr_name impressionWin transactionWin hour
server1   true          true           18:00:00
server2   true          true           18:00:00
```

What is the best way to achieve this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **`join`** with **`get_dummies`**

```
df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.log_type)).groupby(['srvr_name', 'hour']).sum().astype(bool)

                    impressionWin  transactionWin
srvr_name hour
server1   18:00:00           True            True
server2   18:00:00           True            True
```

Comment: @Viren happy to help, if this answer solved your problem feel free to accept it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
df = pd.crosstab([df.srvr_name, df.hour], df.log_type).astype(bool).rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  srvr_name      hour  impressionWin  transactionWin
0   server1  18:00:00           True            True
1   server2  18:00:00           True            True
```